# A "non-trivial" example of a Cauchy sequence that does not converge?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, convergence-divergence, cauchy-sequences

A Cauchy sequence doesn't necessarily converge, e.g. take the sequence $(1/n)$ in the space $(0,1)$.

Maybe my intuition is wrong but I tend to think of this as, "it does converge but what it converges to is not in the space".  Are there any examples of a Cauchy sequence that does not converge and avoids this type of saying?

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Completion_Theorem_(Metric_Space)

Comment: You can construct the _completion_ of $X$ for every metric space $X$, in which every Cauchy sequence converges. So in a way, every example is of the type "it converges, but the limit is not in the space".

Comment: It's better to think of a Cauchy sequence as one that ought to converge but doesn't, owing to the absence of the point to which it 'wants' to converge. The completion supplies the missing point.

Comment: Argh. I just noticed an important omission in that last comment: I meant to write *such a Cauchy sequence*, meaning one that does not converge.

Comment: It is possible to have different metrics on the same set, so that each metric gives rise to a different completion (I'm thinking of p-adic numbers). It is quite possible for a Cauchy Sequence in one metric to be divergent (not a Cauchy Sequence) in an alternative metric. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/465549/462).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For any metric space $Q$ we can define the completion, that is a (bigger) metric space $R$ such that $Q$ is a (dense) subspace of $R$ and all Cauchy sequences in $Q$ have a limit in $R$. So the Cauchy sequences in $Q$ "do converge but what they converge to is not in the space".
This is precisely one way of defining $\mathbb R$ from $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Bingo-it took me several years to understand this conception of Cauchy completion and it's extremely intuitive and powerful. All teachers of analysis should use it.

Answer (score 17):

In fact, there are no examples at all. Any metric space admits a [completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completion_(metric_space)#Completion), and every Cauchy sequence in the original space is again Cauchy in the completion, where it converges.

For your given example, $[0,1]$ is a completion of $(0,1).$

Comment: @downvoter: Care to offer constructive criticism? I fail to see why you'd downvote my answer and not Hagen's.