# Are there non-convergent cauchy sequences?

Tags: real-analysis

By non convergent I mean DIVERGENT and NOT that it converges to a value outside the space.
Examples are appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/471577/a-non-trivial-example-of-a-cauchy-sequence-that-does-not-converge

Comment: It is possible to have different metrics on the same set, each metric gives rise to a different completion (I'm thinking of p-adic numbers). It is quite possible for a Cauchy Sequence in one metric to be divergent in an alternative metric. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number

Answer (score 0):

If you talk only about real sequence you have:
Let $a_{n}$ Cauchy sequence then $a_{n}$ is bounded.

infact for all $\varepsilon>0$ exists $n_{0}$ such that 
$$|a_{n}-a_{m}|<\varepsilon $$
$\forall n,m\geq n_{0}$

if $n\geq n_{0}$
$$|a_{n}|\leq |a_{n}-a_{n_{0}}|+|a_{n_{0}}|<C$$
if $n\leq n_{0}$
$$|a_{n}|\leq C$$

Answer (score 0):

I think I found an example:
(1/x)sin(1/(x-floorx) is convergent i R but not in Z.

Comment: sorry, my bad. That function is not defined from neither N to R neither N to Z...