# What sequence would be an example of a Cauchy sequence that diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In metric space every convergent sequence is a Cauchy sequence, but what about the converse?

Comment: Take $X=(0,1)$ with the usual metrics and $x_n=\frac1n$. (This was asked several times on the site.)

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/471577/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the metric space $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ with the usual distance, and the sequence
$$ 1, \frac12, \frac13, \frac14, \frac15, \ldots $$

In $\mathbb R$ this converges to $0$ (and so it is Cauchy), but $0$ is not an element of the metric space, so it *is not convergent* as a sequence in $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence $(x_n)$ defined by

$$x_{n+1}=\left(x_n+\frac{2}{x_n}\right)\frac12$$

for $x_0>0$ converge to $\sqrt 2$. But if our metric space is $\Bbb Q$ then the sequence doesnt converge on this space.