# convergence of a sequence of cauchy

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I would like to ask something about the convergence of a Cauchy sequence in a space $X$ metric.

There will be a metric space $X$ such that

If $(x_n)$ cauchy sequence in $X$ then $(x_n)$ is not convergent in $Y$ for all, $Y$ such that $X\subset Y$ ?

I give some examples and the answer seems to be not, simply take $\overline{X}$, although
 I'm not sure.

On the other hand, there is definition of cauchy sequence in topological spaces, if any, which would be the answer to the question?

I appreciate the patience and time for each of you, hope you can guide me

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/465549/462).